# Message properties on Mqtt protocol

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm having problems receiving message properties and message system properties on the Mqtt protocol. But it works fine when using TransportType.Amqp.

Is the explanation to be found in section "Receiving messages" at this page?
https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/iot-hub-mqtt-support/
If yes, what does it mean and how do I do that?

Receiver code:
I'm using 1.0.12 of Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client from nuget and all the dependencies.

```
//connectString: HostName=<host name>;DeviceId=<device id>;SharedAccessKey=<key>
//var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectString,TransportType.Amqp);
var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectString, TransportType.Mqtt);
while (true)
{
    var message = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    if (message != null)
    {
        //message.MessageId is null on Mqtt but not for Amqp!
    }
}
```

Sender code:
I’m using version 1.0.11 of Microsoft.Azure.Devices.dll

```
string messageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
var iotHubConnection = "HostName=<host>;SharedAccessKeyName=<...>;SharedAccessKey=<...>";
var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnection);
if (serviceClient == null) throw new Exception("ServiceClient create failed");

var serviceMessage = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World"));
serviceMessage.Ack = DeliveryAcknowledgement.Full;
serviceMessage.MessageId = messageId;
serviceMessage.Properties["message-id"] = messageId;

serviceClient.SendAsync("0123", serviceMessage).Wait();
```

The C sample code reads properties, but but the csharp sample code does not:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_mqtt/iothub_client_sample_mqtt.c

Comment: Problem fixed in version 1.0.13 of Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.